# Updating SQLite database upon changes in Attribute properties

Tags: pyqgis, sqlite

I want to write a script to update the a property of an attribute in the SQLite database automatically.

What I could think of was creating a Python code that accepts 3 inputs, namely the id of the object, the current value of the property and the wanted value of the property.

writting in pure python code, is easily done through:

```
import sqlite3

conn = sqlite3.connect('database.sqlite')
c = conn.cursor()

def change(id,currVal, newVal):
    c.execute("UPDATE table SET specificProperty=? WHERE specificID=? AND specificPropery=?", (newVal, id, currVal))
    conn.commit()


change('this_is_specified_id', 9.57, 11)

c.close()
conn.close()
```

Unfortunately i just found out that pure Python code isn't accepted in PyQGIS. I was still hoping to write my own processing framework, instead of extending the provided processing frameworks, since it doesn't work for me so far. I believe Python console provided in QGIS won't run an external Python script as well.

Comment: QGIS can run any Python just fine but it depends where you want to use to know how to set up things. When or where do you want to trigger this piece of code?

Comment: @bugmenot123 ideally when the value in the attribute table is changed. but i dont mind if i have to run the piece of code manually.

Comment: You could do it using signals but that would be pretty advanced. I'd suggest you start making it a script you can use in the built-in script editor first. https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/user_manual/plugins/python_console.html and https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/vector.html should get you going.